# magento 2 add span tag in price

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, checkout, onepage-checkout, success-message

I am facing an issue with Magento 2 checkout success page.
I have added API for SMS to receive final SMS about the order and when SMS is received its showing the "span" stage around the price like below

```
3 51151 SHJ
**<span class="price">3 AED</span> pos**
Balance: 0
```

my line of code is:

```
$textMsg[] = $formatPrice->currency($order->getGrandTotal()).' '." pos ". $order->getPayment()->getCcStatus();
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the instance of your `$formatPrice` variable is `Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data`

The currency function accepts 3 parameters

```
public function currency($value, $format = true, $includeContainer = true)
{
    return $format
        ? $this->priceCurrency->convertAndFormat($value, $includeContainer)
        : $this->priceCurrency->convert($value);
}
```

In order to remove the `span` element, just do  this

```
$formatPrice->currency($order->getGrandTotal(), true, false)
```